# Pymongo query based on nested element in document

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have data stored in MongoDB as following:

```
{
    "payouts": {
      "entries": [
        {
          "custom_payout_overwrite": false, 
          "entry_name": "", 
          "network_custom_payout_revenue_setting_id": 0, 
          "network_offer_payout_revenue_id": 1, 
          "payout_amount": 0.44, 
          "payout_percentage": 0, 
          "payout_type": "cpa"
        }
      ], 
      "total": 1
    }
}
```

I want to get only data which has payout_amount greater than 0.

I have already tried

```
filter_by = {"payouts.entries.payout_amount": {"$gte": 0}}
data = db[collection_name].find(filter_by)
```

But it's not working I gues. It's because entries is a list and I am not sure how to query further inside a list. Thanks.

Comment: Would you like to get documents or specific entries of `entries` array?

Comment: Documents please

Comment: Tried your query and it works. Could it be that you are querying the wrong collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$elemMatch`:

```
filter_by = {'payouts.entries': {'$elemMatch': {'payout_amount': {'$gte': 0}}}}
data = db[collection_name].find(filter_by)
```

Docs about `$elemMatch` usage is [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/).

Also note: to get only data which has `payout_amount` greater than 0 you should use `$gt` (not `$gte`):

```
filter_by = {'payouts.entries': {'$elemMatch': {'payout_amount': {'$gt': 0}}}}
```

Comment: Thanks tried this but its still giving entries which has amount 0 :(

Comment: @Kishan have you used `$gt` or `$gte` ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. some data has multiple "entries" in the array. so it returns that if any one of the amounts is greater than 0. Thanks.